# Mercurial: Remove file from all changesets

Tags: mercurial

I understand how to [remove an entire changeset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2684898/mercurial-remove-history) from history but it's not clear how to remove a subset instead.

For example, how do I remove all DLL files from an existing changeset while leaving the source-code alone?

Comment: Do the DLLs exist in just the most recent changeset or an earlier changeset (or changesets)?

Comment: The DLLs exist in an earlier changeset.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Because the revision ids (e.g. a8d7641f...) are based on a hash of the changeset, it's not really possible to *remove* a subset of a changeset from history.

However, it is possible to create a new repo with a parallel history, except for a certain set of files, by using the [Convert](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ConvertExtension) extension. You'll be converting a Mercurial repo to a Mercurial repo, using the filemap to exclude the files you don't want by adding `exclude`s. This will create a new, unrelated repository, which means that any clones people have won't be able to pull from it any more, and will have to re-clone from this new repo.

Comment: Is there no other way? Let's say your on a 100 person team. Someone accidentally checks in copyrighted material. Or maybe they check in some userdata by mistake as part of a test. Asking all the devs to re-clone seems like a non-starter but you need to get rid of the data. Is there no other option?

Comment: No. With a team that large, one would hope that there is some kind of review process involved.

Answer (score 13):

1. Make sure all your teammates have pushed their local changes to the
   central repo (if any)
2. Backup your repository
3. Create a "map.txt" file with the following content:

   ```
   # this filemap is used to exclude specific files
   exclude "subdir/filename1.ext"
   exclude "subdir/filename2.ext"
   exclude "subdir2"
   ```
4. Run this command:

   ```
   hg convert --filemap map.txt c:/oldrepo c:/newrepo
   ```

   NOTE: You have to use "forward-slash" in paths, even on windows.
5. Wait and be patient
6. Now you have a new repo at `c:\newrepo` but without the files

PS. In the "upper" repo you have to remove all **changesets** and **re-push** your new repo.

PPS. I actually wrote a [blog post](http://www.jitbit.com/alexblog/232-removing-files-from-mercurial-history/) about this that has more details (including stripping the changesest in Bitbucket etc.

Comment: As new team members are added, I suspect we'll probably do this once a year to keep the repo lean from all the noob commits.

Comment: My cofounder has accidentally committed the entire PhoneGap library into the repo (18 megabytes), so I had to learn this the hard way, hehe

Comment: What about excluding all files of certain type? I tried `"exclude *.bak"` to exclude all backup files from all commits (I forgot to include them in .hgignore), didn't work.