# Mercurial remove changeset, history with merges

Tags: mercurial

I want to [remove a changeset from history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2684898/mercurial-remove-history) but `hg export` does not work for merge changesets (see https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Export). Is there a way to use `hg pull` for a range of revisions? For example, say I want to remove revision 999 I want to be able to say:

```
hg init NewRepo
hg pull ../OldRepo -r 0:1000
hg pull ../OldRepo -r 1000:tip
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pull can't pull a range of revisions because every mercurial revision that exists in a repository must have all of its ancestor changesets in that revision too.  So if you do:

```
hg pull ../oldRepo -r 1000
```

you get all of revision 1000's ancestor revisions too.

In general, mercurial is about building an immutable history -- if you regret a changeset you don't remove it you create a new one that undoes the work of the changeset you no longer like.  If you can't abide having full history in your repo you need to use something like the `strip` or `convert` extension.  Both work as advertised, but provide plenty of opportunities to shoot yourself in the foot.  If you can stand it, just undo the onerous changeset in a subsequent changeset and move on.

Comment: I want to shoot myself in the foot. How can I use hg convert to strip out multiple discrete revisions? For example, given revisions 0 to 1000, I want to remove 205, 405 and 934.

Comment: I think you could use a --splicemap option with convert to make the children of those revisions children of those revisions' parents instead, which would make those revisions heads.  You'd then do a local clone with -r to pull all the heads except those.  I've not tried it because it's not a good idea. :)